# Load an iPad nib from an iPhone class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xib, nib, ipa

I have a universal app.
I wrote all the iPhone code.  Noe, rather than rewrite the code exactly the same, I would like to just have specialized xib files.  How do I set up this new xib files.  How to I create them and how do I link them to my iPhone classes.  then how do I load them, meaning make the app pick the iphone xib or the ipad xib

thanks in advace
Note, I'm using Xcode 3

Answer (score 1):

when you instantiate you controller using alloc init , Use initWithNibName and use the nib or .xib name you to associate with project.

Comment: eh, kinda.  That was part of it, but I also had to do a bunch of other stuff

Answer (score 0):

hmm, you say "I have a universal app", but sounds like you mean "I have an iPhone app and want to create a Universal App". If so, here is some info I used the first time I did this:

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/04/converting-iphone-apps-to-universal.html

Jeff Lamarches stuff is pretty reliable I think.